# Kivy, Python: I cannot reduce the size of the package generated by PyInstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I wrote a small app using python 3 and Kivy. The app is based on a python as well as a kv-file. I wanted to create a package for Windows. Basing on the information found on the official documentation, I was able to create a package but it was really huge! Then I tried to reduce the size of the package excluding the unused libraries. To do this, I followed the official documentation again.

This is the spec-file I created and modified:

```
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal,     hookspath
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\..\\wecker'],             
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=hookspath(),
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             **get_deps_minimal(video=None, audio=None))
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='myweckapp',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('buildtemp'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='myweckapp')
```

When I run the command:

```
python -m PyInstaller --name touchtracer examples-path\demo\touchtracer\main.py
```

I get following error message:

```
WARNING: stderr: TypeError: type object got multiplevalues for keyword argument 'excludes'
```

And I cannot continue. I tried to eliminate the code line:

```
excludes=[],
```

Then I got following message:

```
WARNING: stderr: TypeError: type object got multiplevalues for keyword argument 'hiddenimports'
```

Thus, I also tried to eleiminate this line:

```
hiddenimports=[]
```

Now, I can create a package but is is still huge!

Any idea where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

How huge is it?  I have had similar size problems using PyInstaller before.  I have a few huge modules like IPython, cv2 etc., and PyInstaller doesn't exclude them by default. You can run the following code to get a list of all python modules, installed and built in:

```
import pkgutil
for i in pkgutil.iter_modules():
    print('"'+i[1]+'",')
```

This gets you a list of all installed modules.  Next, run the following command to make the SPEC file:

```
pyi-makespec main.py
```

Next, open the spec file. In the excludes section, paste the list created from the code above. Remove only the ones you need (you will need to remove a couple of the builtins).  See if this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the question... but I'm a newbie. Where do I have to write your code "import pkgutil..."?

Comment: I mean there are a variety of ways you can reduce waste it seems like you're on the right track. What's the full file size what types of media if any are you using. Converting specific files to different types can reduce the overall size with minimal loss in quality if any at all. It's also important to understand that you're essentially building a static application that has all the dependencies of your program. I've done things for myself on test machines where I've bundled Python it's self along with kivy and all the other shit I needed for my tests. Can you give us some more info?

Comment: You can just open IDLE and type it in.  IDLE is the interactive shell for python.  No problem, happy to help.

Comment: Dear Benjamin, what is the best way to get the list of the modules I need and the builtins. I am packaging a Kivy + Python app and the size is approx 300MB!!!! :(